Color row across multiple columns
I have a container with a row containing two colummns.
Each of the two columns contains the same number of rows, like a table.
Now I would like to programmatically highlight a row on demand, so that the highlighting spans visually the whole row over both columns.
On the left side is what I want to achieve, on the right side is my current approach which is not allowing to highlight a single row over two columns.

My problem is that no matter what I set for mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max for the inner rows, they never expand further than the text. Meaning when I highlight the rows by wrapping them each into a container with a color, then there is always a gap between the two rows.
Maybe I am using the wrong construction?
Thanks for your help!

use sizedBox widget for fixed height and width.

and why two columns then? why not one column with 4 or more rows, each row containing 2 evenly spaced items

Add a height and width to the Container widget, then set MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly for the Row. Provide height and width to the Columns as well, and set MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly for them too.
Add a SizedBox between the two Columns to create a gap, and give each Column a separate height and width. Since you are using MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly for the Columns, the spacing between the Rows within each column will be equal.
